# powershell click with $IE.Document.getElementById

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I tried to click on a button with powershell:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'New file'}
$link.click()
```

But this doesn't work.

When I check the button :

```
<div arid=536870904 artype="NavBarItem" ardbn="btnDemande_ANS" type="vert" parentid=301650500 class="VNavLeaf VNavLevel2 arfid536870904 ardbnbtnDemande_ANS" style="padding-left:20&#59;"><a href="javascript:" class="btn" title="">New file</a></div>
```

I dont know why that doesnt work.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What is the contents of `$link` after you try to retrieve the object? And what properties and methods does it contain (`$link | gm`)?

Comment: Is it possible there is more than one match as well.? Following Johans comment would answer that as well.

Comment: when i do ($link | gm) :

Comment: when i do ($link | gm) i have a lot of methods and property I don't know how show you

Comment: can you use IE DOM (F12) - or Right click -> Inspect Element? on the button, and find the ID or the parent classname?

Comment: Hi, i found that <div arid=301650500 artype="NavBarItem" ardbn="z2NM_ConsoleFunctions" status="close" type="vert" parentid=301626400 class="VNavParent VNavLevel1 arfid301650500 ardbnz2NM_ConsoleFunctions" style="padding-left:0&#59;"><a href="javascript:" class="btn" title=""><img alt="" src="../../../../resources/images/vnav_close1.gif">general functions</a></div><div id="sub-301650500" class="VNavSub" style="display:none&#59;visibility:hidden">  The ID is sub-301650500 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the div with:

```
$div = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('VNavLeaf VNavLevel2 arfid536870904 ardbnbtnDemande_ANS') | where-object {$_.arid -eq '536870904' }
```

and then get the link with:

```
$link = $div.getElementsByClassName('btn')
$link.click()
```

This should activate the method click() on the button and not on the div.